# How to get the kendo tab titles?

Tags: jquery, kendo-tabstrip

I want to get kendo tabstrip titles in my js.how to get the all titles of my kendo tabstrip.

```
<div  kendo-tab-strip="vm.tabstrip" k-content-urls="[ null, null]"  
id="tabstrip">
           <ul>
           <li>
               <span>SubContractorRentalItems</span>
           </li>
           <li>
               <span>MLRentalItems</span>
           </li>
           <li>
               <span>SubHiredItems</span>
           </li>
           <li>
               <span>SubHiredAccessories</span>
           </li>    
       </ul>
      </div>
```

So,i want to get all span element titles in my js?how to get that?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of items in the tabstrip using (API reference available [here](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip#methods-items)):

```
$("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip").items();
```

Lets say you add a class "title" to your spans:

```
<div  kendo-tab-strip="vm.tabstrip" k-content-urls="[ null, null]" id="tabstrip">
       <ul>
       <li>
           <span class='title'>SubContractorRentalItems</span>
       </li>
       <li>
           <span class='title'>MLRentalItems</span>
       </li>
       <li>
           <span class='title'>SubHiredItems</span>
       </li>
       <li>
           <span class='title'>SubHiredAccessories</span>
       </li>    
   </ul>
  </div>
```

You could get the titles using:

```
$($("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip").items()).children("li span.title");
```